# Magento 2.4.3: Customer password issue

Tags: magento2.4, frontend-error, password-recovery

Using Magento 2.4.3-p2
Using Porto 4.0.1 theme
Using PHP 7.4

A customer has reported that they were unable to reset their own password.
I've triggered a reset link via the back end (and they have triggered the reset email to get sent to them too)

The reset email arrives and the link takes them to a password reset page, but after they have entered the password (after meeting the minimum requirements) and correctly completed the captcha they get this error message.

[image: Password error image]

I thought this might have been an isolated incident or something to do with the account having been migrated from a very old source... So I created a brand new account and successfully completed the signup process - after logging out and then attempting to trigger my OWN password reset, I too am met with the same error message as above.

**All accounts** - new and old are now unable to reset their passwords if they have forgotten them!

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

You may evaluate that there is in general a problem regarding cookie setting and / or session initating.

I would suggest:

Check **table** session
Check **table** core_config_data
Check **table** customer_entity password_hash field

Check your base_url MUST end with a slash

bin/magento config:set web/secure/base_url
bin/magento config:set web/unsecure/base_url

However first I would check if my changes take effect in the correponding db tables.

You could also simulate first with magento cli

rgds,

Andy

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.

I've confirmed in the database itself and the magento backend that the base URL ends with a slash

Comment: ...also ... Core_config_Data has over 1000 entries, but I can see that the base URL there has the / at the end of the line. Was there something else that I might check?

Table Customer_Entity and column 'password_hash' is populated with a hash value. the rp_token (reset password token) is also populated

Both older accounts and one I have just created appear to be correctly formed in the database.

Comment: You may evaluate DBeaver as your RDMS Tool. Functions and UI is overwhelming but also intimidating. It gives you also graphical overview of relations and much more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to change my custom theme (porto) file:
**`app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Customer/templates/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml`**

and introduce new form param id like following:

```
['id' => $block->getRpCustomerId(), 'token' => $block->getRequest()->getParam("token")]
```